# Fudamental matrix of the adjoint system of homogeneous differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

> Prove that if $y'(t)=A(t)y(t)$ and $\psi(t)=e^{At}$ then $\eta(t)$ is the fudamental matrix of the adjoint system iff $\psi^*\eta$ is a constant invertible matrix.

$A^*(t)$ is the conjugate transpose of the $n\times n$ matrix $A(t)$

It is given $x(t)=-A^*(t)y(t)$ is the adjoint system, but in that case I think we can prove $\psi^*\eta=I$. What really is meant by adjoint system of equations ?

And how do I prove it ?

Comment: Please check again your sources. Is $A(t)$ constant? Is somehow else guaranteed that $A(s)$ commutes with $A(t)$ for all pairs $s,t$? If $x'=-A^*x$ then $(x^*y)'=0$, which would be a valid idea to be named "adjoint".

Comment: @LutzLehmann can you first clarify what really is meant by adjoint system of equations, sorry couldn't get a clar picture of that itself ?

Comment: "adjoint" relates to the equivalent action on linear forms. $y\mapsto x^*y$ is a linear form, "equivalent action" means that this scalar product remains constant. So $0=\dot x^*y+x^*\dot y=\dot x^*y+x^*A y$. Independence from the concrete solution $y$ gives $\dot x^*=-x^*A\iff \dot x=-A^*x$.

Comment: @ss1729 To repeat the first comment, please check whether the question as it is originally stated has an $A(t)$ as opposed to a constant matrix $A$

Comment: Also, regarding your last paragraph: note that a fundamental matrix $\eta(t)$ of the system $y(t) = A(t) x(t)$ is **any** matrix whose columns are linear independent solutions of the system; it is not necessarily the case that $\eta(t) = e^{At}$.

Comment: <s>"linear forms"</s> -> "linear functionals", elements of the dual space or vectors associated to them by the Riesz representation theorem.